# Python и директории

Tags: python

Как мне перейти в какую-либо директорию в Python для дальнейшей работы с ней (Например создание zip-архивов, папок, текстовиков и т. д.)

Comment: почитайте https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os.html

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
os.chdir(path) # смена рабочей директории
```